# How can I fetch a key-value map from JsonNode?

Tags: json, jackson, jsonpath

I have a following JSON file.

```
{
  "data": {
    "k1": "v1",
    "k2": "v2",
    ...
  }
}
```

Is there any way to fetch those keys and values as a `Map<String, String>` using pathpath?

I'm currently doing like this.

```
JsonNode root = ...
JsonNode data = root.get("data");
ObjectReader reader = mapper.readFor(new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
reader.readValue(data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of converstion:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree("{\n" +
                "  \"data\": {\n" +
                "    \"k1\": \"v1\",\n" +
                "    \"k2\": \"v2\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}");
        Map<String,String> map = objectMapper.convertValue(root.get("data"),Map.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create simple `POJO` like below:

```
class Data {
    private Map<String, String> data;

    public Map<String, String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(Map<String, String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Data{" +
                "data=" + data +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Read `JSON` in this way:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Data data = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Data.class);
System.out.println(data);
```

Above code prints:

```
Data{data={k1=v1, k2=v2}}
```